# Query: Password APIs Issue on Salesforce Security Report

Tags: customer-community, security-review, checkmarx

We have a scenario to allow the user to reset the password for the community users, We have used the following snippet

`System.resetPassword(userId, true);`

So its blocked in the security report under the section **Query: Password APIs**, So do we have any other way to reset the password or any solution to by-pass this in security review, will false positive be sufficient for this?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to elaborate on what you mean by "blocked". Just having a report point something out is not blocking you, it is trying to draw your attention to potentially dangerous code.

On the other hand if you were failed in the (manual) security review, then you should have received a more detailed explanation, and you have the opportunity to book office hours to have the findings explained to you. Failing the security review is a real blocker, having an automated tool generate a report is not a blocker.

In terms of the actual security issues here, why are you accepting the userId as a parameter instead of pulling it from the UserInfo class? Is the intention to allow anyone to reset anyone else's password? If so, what type of access control are you enforcing? Can a guest user reset an admin's password? What, in your code, prevents that? Remember that your apex code is running in system mode and that anyone can call auraEnabled methods with any parameter, and thus they can supply any userId parameter.

Because of this, you can create a serious problem for whatever organization is hosting your code unless you do access control checks in apex before resetting passwords. This is why these are considered dangerous functions and why they are flagged.

Comment: Robert, We're not accepting the userId as param, we're taking from UserInfo.getUserId class and assigning to variable for other usage purpose. But while submitting the report to  security review, having this bug in report wont cause any issue for review?

Comment: If you are getting it from userInfo you should be OK